# heroku db:push Error: time zone displacement out of range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, timezone

I made a `heroku db:push`

at first it went fine

```
Sending schema
Schema:        100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:06
Sending indexes
schema_migrat: 100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:01
Sending data
3 tables, 8 records
schema_migrat: 100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:00
users:           0% |                                          | ETA:  --:--:--
Saving session to push_201204102202.dat..
```

these are the contents of the push_201204102202.dat file:

```
    {"klass":"Taps::Push","database_url":"sqlite://db/development.sqlite3","remote_url":"http://heroku:osui59a24am79x@taps19.heroku.com","session_uri":"/sessions/7436189125","stream_state":{},"completed_tables":["schema_migrations"],"table_filter":null,"local_tables_info":{"schema_migrations":2,"users":4,"microposts":2}}
```

then trouble started:

```
    !!! Caught Server Exception
    HTTP CODE: 500
    Taps Server Error: PGError: ERROR:  time zone displacement out of range: "2012-04-10 12:00:00.000000+5894467200"



    ["/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel3.20.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:175:in `async_exec'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/seq
uel/adapters/postgres.rb:175:in `block (2 levels) in execute'","/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-.20.0/lib/sequel/database/logging.rb:28:in`log_yield'","/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-.20.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:175:in `block in execute'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-.20.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:158:in`check_disconnect_errors'","/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:175:in `execute'","/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-.20.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:240:in `block (2 levels) in execute'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:71:in`hold'","/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:226:in `synchronize'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:240:in `block in execute'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:261:in `check_database_errors'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.r
b:238:in `execute'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/database/query.rb:71:in `execute_dui'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/dataset/actions.rb:552:in `execute_dui'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/dataset/actions.rb:243:in `block (2 l
evels) in import'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/dataset/actions.rb:243:in `each'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.2
0.0/lib/sequel/dataset/actions.rb:243:in `block in import'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/database/query.rb:223:in `_transaction'
", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/database/query.rb:209:in `block in transaction'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.
0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:84:in `hold'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:226:in `synchronize'"
, "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/database/query.rb:207:in `transaction'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequ
el/dataset/actions.rb:243:in `import'", "/app/lib/taps/data_stream.rb:315:in `import_rows'", "/app/lib/taps/data_stream.rb:158:in `fetch_remote_in_server'", "/a
pp/lib/taps/server.rb:114:in `block (3 levels) in '", "/app/lib/taps/utils.rb:161:in `call'", "/app/lib/taps/utils.rb:161:in `server_error_handlin
g'", "/app/lib/taps/server.rb:112:in `block (2 levels) in '", "/app/lib/taps/db_session.rb:15:in `block in conn'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/g
ems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:76:in `connect'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:119:in `connect'", "/a
pp/lib/taps/db_session.rb:14:in `conn'", "/app/lib/taps/server.rb:111:in `block in '", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/
base.rb:865:in `call'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:865:in `block in route'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-
1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:521:in `instance_eval'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:521:in `route_eval'", "/app/.bundle/gems/rub
y/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:500:in `block (2 levels) in route!'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:497:in `ca
tch'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:497:in `block in route!'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/
base.rb:476:in `each'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:476:in `route!'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/
sinatra/base.rb:601:in `dispatch!'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:411:in `block in call!'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/
gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `instance_eval'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `block in invoke'", "/ap
p/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `catch'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `invok
e'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:411:in `call!'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:399:
in `call'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:979:in `block in call'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinat
ra/base.rb:1005:in `synchronize'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:979:in `call'", "/home/heroku_rack/lib/static_assets.rb:9:
in `call'", "/home/heroku_rack/lib/last_access.rb:15:in `call'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:47:in `block in call'", "/app/
.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:41:in `each'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:41:in `call'", "/home
/heroku_rack/lib/date_header.rb:14:in `call'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:77:in `call'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/ge
ms/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/connection.rb:76:in `block in pre_process'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/connection.rb:74:in `catch'", "/app/.
bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/connection.rb:74:in `pre_process'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/connection.rb:57:in `
process'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/connection.rb:42:in `receive_data'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/l
ib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run_machine'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:57:in `start'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/server.rb:156:in `start'", "/app/.bundle/gem
s/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:80:in `start'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/runner.rb:177:in `run_com
mand'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/runner.rb:143:in `run!'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/bin/thin:6:in `'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `load'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `'"]
```

Comment: The error shows: `2012-04-10 12:00:00.000000+5894467200`; there's no way to parse the `+5894467200` as a valid time zone offset from UTC, and the message says as much.  So, you're going to have to track down how on earth you got such a value.

Comment: Check out this SO question ...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151571/error-when-pushing-data-to-heroku-time-zone-displacement-out-of-range (they had a solution that worked but not sure if it'll apply to you).

Answer (score 7):

This is a ruby 1.9.3 error. You should be using 1.9.2 with db:push in order to work. If you have rvm installed you can do it this way:

```
rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p318
heroku db:push
```

make sure you use the proper 1.9.2 version I giving p318 as an example because I have it installed on my end. To see the installed ruby versions with rvm use `rvm list`. If you don't have 1.9.2 installed use `rvm install ruby-1.9.2`

Comment: I somehow needed to specify path of ruby(even if I use "rvm use ruby-1.9.2-...").

$ ~/.rvm/bin/ruby-1.9.2-p320 /usr/bin/heroku db:push

Comment: This may be due to the fact that there is a Heroku gem and Heroku Toolbelt. I think that they both provide a heroku command. As far as I know the gem is deprecated and only the Heroku Toolbelt should be used. This is just a wild guess.

Answer (score 1):

Use a gemset with Ruby 1.9.2, install taps and sqlite3, you will be fine.

```
sudo gem install heroku --no-ri --no-rdoc

sudo gem install taps --no-ri --no-rdoc

sudo gem install sqlite3 --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

Comment: this was useful, combined with the above answer.  Switched to 1.9.2 and then gem installed (not sudo cos its rvm) all three gems.  Win.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this to work with help from Dosha's answer [here](https://github.com/ricardochimal/taps/issues/92#issuecomment-11996909).

Make sure your version of ruby matches the version running on Heroku. It seems like 1.9.2 is the stablest version for these migrations.

Change your gemfile to have the following (assuming you're using SQLite):

```
group :development do
 gem 'taps', :require => false
 gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

This likely still does not resolve your problem because your `heroku db:push` command is using the Heroku toolbar instead of the older, now-deprecated heroku gem. Unfortunately, we actually want the older gem, but the Heroku Toolbar is being called by `heroku`. To get around this, you will need to install the heroku gem on your version of ruby 1.9.2 and then access it by its specific filepath.

So, the next steps show how you can get this to work:

Run the following commands into your console:

```
rvm install ruby-1.9.2-p320
rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p320
bundle install`
sudo gem install heroku --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

Then run:

```
rake assets:clean
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Commit your changes to Github.

Then enter the following into your console:

`~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/heroku-2.40.0/bin/heroku db:push`
(Use your own filepath, if it's different from this.)