# why Heroku does not download database updates with 'Heroku db: pull'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, postgresql, heroku

I have run 'heroku db:push' to download heroku db updates, it show me error:

taps load error: no such file to load --sqlite3
you may need to install or update the taps gem to use db commands.
on most systems this will be: 
sudo gem install taps

I have installed heroku 2.25.0, taps 0.3.24 and I changed the Gemfile replacing gem sqlite3 with:

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

I think it's a problem of compatibility database between sqlite e postgresql.

is it possible? Or what can be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you've got your gems all up to date by running `bundle install`. It won't hurt if everything's fine so you may as well make sure.

After that, you should be able to use `db:pull` to pull a copy to your local machine using the snippet that follows:

```
bundle exec heroku db:pull sqlite://local.db --app my_app
```

If this doesn't work for some reason, you can just change your Gemfile while pulling the database down -- and then you can change it back if you want to.

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  # add this next line and run 'bundle install' until you get db:pull to work
  gem 'pg'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

(I believe this will work, though I personally haven't tried it. Please respond if there's an issue.)

Finally, there are some issues pulling and pushing databases if you're running *ruby 1.9.3 on your local machine* -- but it's only if you're doing a `db:push`. [If you have problems with that here's a link to the solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151571/error-when-pushing-data-to-heroku-time-zone-displacement-out-of-range/10129060#10129060)

Answer (score 0):

When you run the `heroku` command, it runs locally on your development machine. So the `development` group of your Gemfile is used:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

Since it contains `sqlite3`, you need the `sqlite3` gem to be installed on your development machine. Have you run `bundle install` to install this gem locally? And you may need to run the `heroku` command within a `bundle exec` call to make sure the gems are loaded:

`bundle exec heroku db:pull`.

Finally, if you want to download Heroku DB, you should use `db:pull`, not `db:push`.

Comment: yes yes, i have run 'heroku db:pull', write error, and I had already installed sqlite gem locally.