# heroku db:push error with toolbelt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, sqlite, taps

Is there a way to download Heroku toolbelt with ruby 1.9.3 ?
Now It automatically installs 1.9.2 from the homepage - https://toolbelt.heroku.com/.

Can't do db:push to Heroku, because of this.

---

**Update**

I found it here - http://assets.heroku.com/heroku-toolbelt/heroku-toolbelt-2.25.1.exe

Comment: You can tell Heroku to use a different version of ruby via the Gemfile; the version of ruby used for the toolbelt itself should be irrelevant.  Is there a specific reason you can't deploy because of the toolbelt ruby version specifically?

Comment: I was trying different options, because there are some issues between ruby 1.9.2 and 1.9.3 on heroku. Check out the update. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see https://github.com/heroku/toolbelt/issues/26

you can use ruby 1.9.3 if you put the ruby1.9.3 path before the heroku path 
you can verify with `heroku version`

basically, heroku want to works with ruby 1.9.2 due to compatibiltiy issue with other versions so it install its own version.

also check your heroku version that you are using the toolbelt and not the gem

Comment: This worked. But I ran into different problem - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

My problem occurred, because the current toolbelt automatically installs ruby 1.9.2 in C:/Pogram files, although on my local machine I have ruby 1.9.3 in C:/ via http://railsinstaller.org/

This created a little mess with my **path**.

I had to take out toolbet's ruby off the **path** and this solved the issue I started this question with.

But doing `heroku db:push` with Ruby 1.9.3. got me into `time zone displacement'error`. 
Which is another problem and discussed in more detail here:

[Error when pushing data to Heroku: time zone displacement out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151571/error-when-pushing-data-to-heroku-time-zone-displacement-out-of-range)

The solution is to switch completely to 1.9.2 locally.
But since I'm on windows 7, this as well caused some trouble since most solutions I found were for OSX

But finally I managed to get it to work by switching to R 1.9.2 locally using https://github.com/vertiginous/pik