# Error installing RVM. Error: BASH 3.2.25 required (you have 3.1.0(1)-release)

Tags: ruby, windows, bash, heroku, rvm

My goal is to push the contents of my local database to Heroku. Using the

```
heroku db:push --app my-app
```

I get the same error as in this question: [Error when pushing data to Heroku: time zone displacement out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151571/error-when-pushing-data-to-heroku-time-zone-displacement-out-of-range)

> Taps Server Error: PGError: ERROR:  time zone displacement out of range: "2012-12-19 12:00:00.000000+5895074400"

The solution as widely accepted in the above question is:

> Using Ruby 1.9.2-p290 instead of 1.9.3-p0

In order to implement this solution and change my Ruby version I am trying to install RVM. When I follow the installation instructions:

> curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby

I get the following error:

> BASH 3.2.25 required (you have 3.1.0(1)-release)

How do I update to Bash 3.2.25 on Windows? I have searched and tried updating git, git bash, win-bash. My bash.exe file shows modified today 1/18/13 but when the version after startup says 3.1. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more searching, trial and error I reached out to a couple of seasoned developers who recommended Cygwin. The initial install and setup of Cygwin did not go smoothly. It was suggested that there might be conflicts with the existing setup on my machine. I decided to start with a clean install of Windows 7, install Cygwin, Ruby, Rails etc from scratch. I now have a fully functional development environment with RVM installed. Liking Cygwin.